# USQL Execution and refer another script

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Could you guys help with following:

1. How can we execute script usql script stored in ADL store using ADF. What is standard practice of storing script?
2. Currently I don't see a way to refer script from another script. It will make script execution simple because then I can make a deep chain where ScriptA will refer to ScriptB and so on and Only submitting ScriptB would be sufficient since it will automatically invoke dependent script.

   3. Please point me to documentation for recommendation for better partition/indexing schema and performance improvement tips/tricks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute U-SQL script in ADL storage from Data Factory in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739628/execute-u-sql-script-in-adl-storage-from-data-factory-in-azure)

Answer (score 1):

1. This was just asked and answered here: [Execute U-SQL script in ADL storage from Data Factory in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43739628/execute-u-sql-script-in-adl-storage-from-data-factory-in-azure)
2. U-SQL offers you a meta-data service with Procedures and Functions. So instead of doing file chaining, you can register your reusable script components as procedures and functions instead.
3. take a look at the performance tuning slides on http://www.slideshare.net/MichaelRys. If you have access to SQLPASS or TechReady presentation recordings, there are videos of that presentation available as well.